# Vuex: Append multiple items to store within mutation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have the following store:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({

  plugins: [createPersistedState()],

  state: {
    data: [
      {symbol: '', price: ''}
    ]
  },

  mutations: {
    RECEIVE_PRICE(state, {symbol, price}) {
      state.data = {
        symbol: symbol,
        price: price
      }
      // state.data.push({
      //   symbol: symbol,
      //   price: price
      // });
    }
  },

  actions: {
    async FETCH_PRICE({commit}, payload) {
      const url = `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=${payload.symbol}&tsyms=${payload.currency}`;
      const {data} = await axios.get(url);
      commit('RECEIVE_PRICE', {
        symbol: payload.symbol,
        price: data[payload.currency]
      });
    }
  },

  getters: {
    crypto_prices: state => {
      return state;
    }
  }
})
```

In my component I have a form with three inputs for *Symbol*, *Amount* and *Currency*.

When I call my getter in my component `computed: mapGetters(['crypto_prices'])` I get the data back from my getter (OK).

**Problem:**

When I add a new crypto, my store gets overwritten with the new data.
How can I append it in my mutation?

I tried it with `store.data.push({...})` but then I have duplicates...

Comment: So basically you want to merge two arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use push for that. If you don't want any duplicates, you have to find an existing entry and exchange it with the new one like so:

```
const index = state.data.findIndex(d => d.symbol === symbol)
if (index === -1) 
  state.data.push({symbol, price});
else 
  state.data[index] = {symbol, price}
```

Comment: I think you meant to write `findIndex`? `find` would return `undefined` if nothing was found.

Answer (score 2):

To add into your store, you would call an *action*:

```
async ADD_CRYPTO({commit}, payload) {
  //save to db or whatnot.  Upon success...
  commit('set_crypto', <payload or server data>);
}
```

Then you add it through a mutation:

```
set_crypto(state, crypto) {
    state.data.unshift(crypto);
},
```

The other thing you might want to consider is renaming "data" in your store to crypto, currencies or something else more descriptive, simply because the way that vue uses the word data.

Also, in your getters you could then call just that item as your store grows...

```
 currencies: state => {
    return state.currencies;
},
```